# How to find chapter number outside of XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an XML and XSL to create a HTML document based on a book. All files are called **chapter-1.xml**, **chapter-2.xml** etc. And the title in each chapter will begin with the chapter # followed by chapter title. The chapters will be written by different people, so each chapter must be in each xml-file.

XML:

```
<chapter title="This is the first chapter">
<paragraph title="Start">Blablabla</paragraph>
</chapter>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="chapter">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/></h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/></h2><br><br>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have a PHP to create the HTML:

```
<?php
# LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load('chapter-1.xml');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('chapter.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
?>
```

And I want this to show as "1. This is the first chapter" in the HTML. Is there anyway to solves this without using another attribute in the tag? Each document only have 1 chapter-tag. Is there a way to solve this with CSS, or by getting the chapter number from the filename or so?

I also need to create a table-of-contents for all the chapters with numbering.

Comment: This question is unclear. Show a snippet of your (if not the entire) stylesheet, and the output you expect. Are you controlling the structure of your input files yourself?

Comment: Better now? I don't have any CSS yet.

Comment: Better, but still: What is your approach to adress the problem you posted? I am not convinced that you really tried to solve this yourself. Also, show more of the stylesheet (if you can use for-each like this, how did you collect all the chapter elements, being in separate files each, as you claim?).

Comment: I did not collect all chapter elements. As I said, there is only 1 chapter element in each document. And I need to put their numbers into the titles of each document. That's my challenge. Well, this is my first project with XML, so I can assure you I've actually been searching and trying for a while now. I don't even know if there really is a way to make this work, without adding a new attribute to each element for numbering. I'm sorry if my questions sounds confusing, but it's a result of having just started with XML. (Also added php code)

Comment: I *think* (I don't know for sure and I don't know how) that you can use PHP to send a *parameter* with the source XML file's name to the XSLT stylesheet. I don't think there's another way, at least not in XSLT 1.0 (which I believe is what PHP is using). There is a lesson here: a file's name is not the proper place to store meaningful content.

Comment: Another possibility is to add a table-of-contents document to the mix, and tell your stylesheet to lookup the chapter's name and position there. This is a good method to use if you often reorder the chapters and don't want to hard-code the number in each chapter's document.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for @user3016153. Would appreciate it if you wrote an answer about it.

Comment: I mentioned two possibilities - which one do you mean when you say "exactly exactly what I'm looking for"?

Comment: The one with adding a table-of-contents document, and tell my stylesheet to lookup chapters name and position there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a document named 'toc.xml', located in the same directory as your stylesheet, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toc>
<chapter num="1" title="First Chapter"/>
<chapter num="2" title="Second Chapter"/>
<chapter num="3" title="Inserted Chapter"/>
<chapter num="4" title="Third Chapter"/>
<chapter num="5" title="Last Chapter"/>
<chapter num="6" title="Last Minute Chapter"/>
</toc>
```

And suppose your 'chapter-3.xml' document looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<chapter title="Third Chapter">
    <paragraph title="Start">Lorem ipsum ... </paragraph>
    <paragraph title="End">...nota bene.</paragraph>
</chapter>
```

Now, applying the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="toc" select="document('toc.xml')/toc" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

<xsl:variable name="chapTitle" select="chapter/@title" />
<xsl:variable name="chapNum" select="$toc/chapter[@title=$chapTitle]/@num"/>

<h1><xsl:value-of select="concat($chapNum, '. ', $chapTitle)"/></h1>

<xsl:for-each select="chapter/paragraph">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></h2>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
<h4><xsl:value-of select="concat('Next chapter: ', $toc/chapter[$chapNum+1]/@title)"/></h4>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this result:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>4. Third Chapter</h1>
      <h2>Start</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>
      <h2>End</h2>
      <p>...nota bene.</p>
      <h4>Next chapter: Last Chapter</h4>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @janlindso Please do.

Comment: Seems like the closest I could come. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your code does not make any sense really, I'm afraid, this is the general idea how to adress a problem like yours.

**Controlling your input**

It is inconvenient to have separate XML files for the `chapter` nodes. So if you are producing these files yourself, make sure to generate all the `chapter` elements in the same XML file, e.g. like this:

```
<chapters>
 <chapter title="This is the first chapter">
    <paragraph title="Start">Blablabla</paragraph>
 </chapter>
 <chapter title="xy">
    <paragraph title="Start">Blablabla</paragraph>
 </chapter>
</chapters>
```

The smartest way to do this is to introduce a numbering attribute at this stage already. If you are unable to alter the input structures, use the `document()` function of XSLT to include several XML files in your transformation.

**Use `xsl:for-each` and `position()` to generate a numbering**

If you manage to group your elements together in one single file, number them with an attribute. For instance,

```
<xsl:variable name="chaps" select="//chapter"/>

<xsl:template match="chapters">
   <xsl:for-each select="$chaps">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="nr">
           <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could also make use of `xsl:number` for this.

**Q & A**

> Is there anyway to solves this without using another attribute in the
>   tag?

Yes, produce the numbering directly in the HTML output with either of the two methods.

> Is there a way to solve this with CSS, or by getting the chapter
>   number from the filename or so?

Trying to solve this in CSS is a bad idea. CSS is about styling a document, not about changing the content. I would also advise against relying on file names when transforming documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer(s). Unfortunately, the chapters will be put together by different people, so it is necessary to find an approach with different filenames. The latest mentioned solution by @user3016153 is close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @janlindso if this method did not work for you then you should consider updating your question to include additional relevant information so that hopefully the next answer someone crafts will fit all of your constraints.

Comment: @jalindso I can only repeat myself: If you ask a broad question that is open to contestation, you can only expect broad and general answers. Please keep this in mind for future posts.